# Failed to load class for data source: com.databricks.spark.csv

Tags: apache-spark

My `build.sbt` file has this:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.3"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.1.0"
```

I am running Spark in standalone cluster mode and my SparkConf is `SparkConf().setMaster("spark://ec2-[ip].compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077").setAppName("Simple Application")` (I am not using the method `setJars`, not sure whether I need it).

I package the jar using the command `sbt package`. Command I use to run the application is `./bin/spark-submit --master spark://ec2-[ip].compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 --class "[classname]" target/scala-2.10/[jarname]_2.10-1.0.jar`.

On running this, I get this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load class for data source:
>   com.databricks.spark.csv

What's the issue?

Comment: How are you packaging your jar?

Comment: @JustinPihony `sbt package`

Comment: @kamalbanga what does that mean ? If you don't want to accept any answer, please delete your question !

Answer (score 3):

Use the dependencies accordingly. For example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-csv_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Include the option: --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.2.0 but do it after --class and before the target/

Comment: This is actually a valid answer which doesn't need to specify explicit jar location.

Comment: Here's how to do it

    `spark-submit --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0 target/scala-2.11/sample-project_2.10-1.0.jar`

Answer (score 0):

add `--jars` option and download the jars below from repository such as search.maven.org

```
--jars commons-csv-1.1.jar,spark-csv-csv.jar,univocity-parsers-1.5.1.jar \
```

Use the `--packages` option as claudiaann1 suggested also works if you have internet access without proxy. If you need to go through proxy, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example that worked: **spark-submit --jars file:/root/Downloads/jars/spark-csv_2.10-1.0.3.jar,file:/root/Downloads/jars/com‌​mons-csv-1.2.jar,file:/root/Downloads/jars/spark-sql_2.11-1.4.1.jar --class "SampleApp" --master local[2] target/scala-2.11/my-proj_2.11-1.0.jar**

Answer (score 0):

Use below Command , its working :

```
spark-submit --class ur_class_name --master local[*] --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0 project_path/target/scala-2.10/jar_name.jar
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using the --packages argument with spark-submit? I've run into this issue with spark not respecting the dependencies listed as libraryDependencies.

Try this:

```
./bin/spark-submit --master spark://ec2-[ip].compute-1.amazonaws.com:7077 
                   --class "[classname]" target/scala-2.10/[jarname]_2.10-1.0.jar
                   --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.1.0
```

_

From the Spark Docs:

> Users may also include any other dependencies by supplying a comma-delimited list of maven coordinates with --packages. All transitive dependencies will be handled when using this command.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#advanced-dependency-management

Comment: Tried that, didn't help.