# Maven: Failed to load class for data source: com.databricks.spark.csv

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I have a Maven project and I can't make it run:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to load class for data source: com.databricks.spark.csv.
```

How to fix this in Maven?

---

PS: I know about this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596670/failed-to-load-class-for-data-source-com-databricks-spark-csv), but I cannot use any additional options to `spark-submit`, except `--class` and `--master`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try **maven-shade-plugin** in you pom it will create one shade jar with your all dependencies or classes. For more detail go through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32265456/how-to-pre-package-external-libraries-when-using-spark-on-a-mesos-cluster/32403191#32403191)

Comment: Extract your shade jar and check, all required class files are available or not.